# How to enable GCP Composer UI access by environment name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-iam

I have multiple cloud composer environments in the same GCP project. I want to give a given user access only to one of these environments. I already created a role with the following permissions:

- composer.dags.execute
- composer.dags.get
- composer.dags.getSourceCode
- composer.dags.list

How can I restrict which environment the user has access to?

I can't anything related to IAM conditions for composer in GCP docs.